# Create dynamic table in word template to export from C#

Tags: c#, templates, datagrid, ms-word, export-to-word

How I can create a dynamic table in a word template? I want it to be used to export a word document from a C# application which contains dynamic grids. The grids in the C# application have static number of columns but the rows can vary.

Comment: How do you plan to use the template? What have you tried already?

Comment: @NetMage I have tried already to export text and numeric fields with success using MergeFields. But I cant find out how I can build a dynamic table. I will use the template in my C# application to export a word file with the fields and tables